# What's the solution to this problem? I did it but I want to make sure Ii got it right

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Rex, Remski Catsakoff and Rudolfo, are back with another logic problem. Using the
variables as indicated below, translate the following English sentences into propositions and
then provide a formal proof to show the conclusion: Nigel does not play with Rudolfo. Remski
is calm or Rudy is not thin. If Nigel is not short or Rudy is thin, then Rudy dislikes corn. If
Nigel is short then he plays with Rudolfo. If Nigel is not short or Rudolfo dislikes corn then
Remski is not calm. Use a formal argument to show that Rudolfo is not thin.
variable means

p Nigel is short

q Rudolfo is thin

r Rudolfo dislikes corn

s Remski is calm

t Nigel plays with Rudolfo

Comment: You said you did it, so please show the work you've done in your post.

Comment: It $t$ stand for "Nigel plays with Rudolfo", what will be "Nigel does **not** play with Rudolfo" ? A little effort may help...